# Custom folder for wordpress page templates

Tags: pages, page-template, directory

How I can change a folder for wordpress page templates?
By default all page templates located in theme's root folder. I want to make a folder with name "templates" in theme's root directory and keep all page templates there.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress 3.4, themes can now place page templates inside a subdirectory of their theme.  via an API called WP_theme. Read more here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20103